# What is the difference between BottomDialogSheet and Backdrop in Android?

Tags: android

I am confused and want to know What is the difference between BottomDialogSheet and Backdrop in Android?

Both appear from bottom and are swipable. Then what is the difference between both?

Comment: I believe the "Backdrop" is implemented with a CoordinatorLayout + a [BottomSheetBehavior](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/) using Material Design. In fact the [Backdrop](https://material.io/components/backdrop) documentation only points to the "specs" but nothing on the Implementation side... I've done this "backdrop" thingy with the above (coordinator +bottom sheet).

Answer (score 2):

A backdrop appears behind all other surfaces or views

Backdrop is used in a different way as explain [here](https://material.io/components/backdrop)

Main differences between Sheets and backdrop are

- In a way backdrop makes out app looks like it is working inside a sheet
- We interact with the backdrop to change menus, filter data, etc.
- Sheets have default elevation of `8dp` or `16dp` whereas views in front of Backdrop have default elevation of `0dp` or `1dp`
- Backdrop is mostly used as the main container whereas dialogSheets are used as optional or showing additional options

Please keep free to edit and add more differences or example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

A backdrop is composed of two surfaces: a back layer and a front layer. The back layer displays actions and context, and these control and inform the front layer’s content. I highly recommend you to follow this [Codelab to implement Backdrop](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/mdc-104-java#0).

Where as [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog#summary) is basically a [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog) styled as [BottomSheet](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom).